# utf8 "\xFF" does not map to Unicode at tokenizer.perl line 44, <STDIN> line 1.

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, tokenize

I am using a perl tokenizer for German. The tokenizer works fine for some files but now I am facing the following error:

```
perl tokenizer.perl -l de < ~/Desktop/me.txt > ~/Desktop/me.txt.tok 
Tokenizer v3
Language: de
utf8 "\xFF" does not map to Unicode at tokenizer.perl line 44, <STDIN> line 1.
Malformed UTF-8 character (byte 0xff) in pattern match (m//) at tokenizer.perl line 45, <STDIN> line 1.
Malformed UTF-8 character (byte 0xff) in pattern match (m//) at tokenizer.perl line 45, <STDIN> line 1.
Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at tokenizer.perl line 64, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Neg.

Comment: Your file isn't valid UTF8.  You need to read it using the correct encoding.

Comment: So, is there a way to convert it into valide UTF8? I try to do it in this way in python: for i in open('file.txt').readlines() print i.encode('utf-8'); but this is raising another error.

Comment: _You cannot magically read a file_.  You need to somehow find out what the correct encoding is, then tell Python to decode the bytes into a string using that encoding.

Comment: In short, you need to learn what text encodings are. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Answer (score 3):

The error message is misleading, but the intended information is correct and useful: the byte FF (hexadecimal) was encountered in the data, but it cannot appear in UTF-8 data. So “utf8 "\xFF"” is nonsense as such, but read it as “byte FF encountered as data purported to be UTF-8 encoded”. Similarly, read “Malformed UTF-8 character (byte 0xff)” as “Invalid data (byte FF) encountered in purported UTF8 data”.

To find out why your data contains the byte FF, you need to reveal more of it. My guess is that it is actually part of a byte order mark in UTF-16 encoding, but this is just a guess.

Comment: Another clue is that when I read the file in python the first line starts with ?? I tried to convert the string using .encode('utf-16') but still that won't help.

Comment: You need to know what the encoding of the data is, or at least make an intelligent guess. We have no data to make a guess about.

Comment: I don't exactly know the encoding but the data is converted into text format from pdf files. I am glad to share some of the files.

Comment: @user89423, share a bit of the file rendered using `od -t x1`. Ideally, include what you expect the text to be.

Comment: @ikegami, I don't how to use share using od -t x1, is it that command. Here are first four lines from my file: Dissertation zur Erlangung des Grades eines Doktors der Naturwissenschaften
der Fakultät für Biologie der Ruhr- Universität Bochum
angefertigt am Lehrstuhl für Allgemeine Zoologie und Neurobiologie
vorgelegt von Matthias Klar
-------And what I want is to make it proper uft-8 file. For me it looks fine but the problem is when reading in my programs. I prefer if the code is in python.

Comment: Files don't contain letters. Letters are obtained after decoding the bytes (numbers) in a file. The problem is with the file, so that's what we need to see. The `od -t x1 file | head -n 10` command will give a hex dump of the first 160 bytes of file `file`.

Comment: If you want to learn how to create a UTF-8 file in python, that's an entirely different question than the one asked.

Comment: @ikegami, here it's: 0000000    ff  fe  44  00  69  00  73  00  73  00  65  00  72  00  74  00
0000020    61  00  74  00  69  00  6f  00  6e  00  20  00  7a  00  75  00
0000040    72  00  20  00  45  00  72  00  6c  00  61  00  6e  00  67  00
0000060    75  00  6e  00  67  00  20  00  64  00  65  00  73  00  20  00
0000100    47  00  72  00  61  00  64  00  65  00  73  00  20  00  65  00

Comment: @ikegami, yeah, you right. I made it twisted into python code because I have no idea about perl. I am using perl tool but I can correctly write the files in utf-8 using python and then I can run them using the perl tool.

Comment: I realise that's what happened. I meant if you have trouble with creating a UTF-8 file in python, you should post a (proper) question about that.

Comment: Try `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF8 ~/Desktop/me.txt | perl tokenizer.perl -l de > ~/Desktop/me.txt.tok` This is assuming that your input file is in UTF-16LE.